# Google Calendar V3 2 Legged authentication fails

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create web page that access the (business) private calendar of the company and insert events if the time slot is available. Still I'm facing an authentication problem.

The [API manual states](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#auth) that I should use an API key and Oauth2LeggedAuthenticator, so I did all this and the request that is fired is quite okey (it has a oauth token and such) But still the response is an exception with **Invalid Credentials**; Easy to say is that my credentials are wrong, still clientID, clientSecret and API Key are valid; I doubt the 2 last params of the 2legged authenticater, is this correct?

```
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
provider.ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID;
provider.ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret;

var authenticator =
new OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator(ClientCredentials.ClientID, ClientCredentials.ClientSecret, "myworkusername", "workdomain.com");


Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService service = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService(authenticator);

service.Key = ClientCredentials.ApiKey;


var result = service.CalendarList.List().Fetch();

Assert.IsTrue(result.Items.Count > 0);
```

Comment: The .NET lib and auth for Calendar is whacky. I haven't figured it out myself... There is this post, where someone seemingly was able to get it working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537681/google-api-v3-for-dotnet-using-the-calendar-with-an-api-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NB: At the time of writing you can only used 2-legged authentication with Google Apps for Business/Eduction, this won't work on personal accounts as there's no way to get an OAuth 1.0 key/secret pair, you will have to use online authentication at least once (but you can use the out-of-browser option so you don't have to create a dedicated page).

Your code is correct apart from you don't need the first three lines relating to the `NativeApplicationClient`. This is most likely failing because you haven't properly set the OAuth keys, this causes 401s.

The other thing that causes 401s is using "matt@example.com" instead of "matt" as the username, the username is without including your domain.

To setup OAuth follow the instructions in [this article](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=162106) from Google.

The most important parts to note are "Allow access to all APIs" must be **unchecked** and you have to individually grant access to all the APIs. If this hasn't been done you will get a `401 Invalid Credentials` error. You then also need to turn those services on in the [api console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). If the api console step hasn't been done you will get a different error of `403 Daily Limit Exceeded`.

This will cause you problems if you were previously relying on the "Allow access to all APIs" to use various services, you will have to grant them all individually as far as I understand it to use the v3 APIs. This seems to [have been confirmed by google](http://groups.google.com/group/google-tasks-api/browse_thread/thread/655471ee1abef19c) (4th reply by Nicolas Garnier) and is supposedly a bug, but that is an old post so it looks as if it's here to stay.

For reference once this has been done, this code will work, which in essence is the same as yours:

```
var auth = new OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator(domainName, consumerSecret, usernameWithoutDomain, domainName);  //domainName is presently used as the OAuth ConsumerKey for Google's 2legged OAuth

var service = new CalendarService(auth);

service.Key = serviceKey;

var results = service.CalendarList.List().Fetch();

Console.WriteLine(results.Items.Count);
```

So in summary:

In Google Apps "Manage this Domain" > "Advanced Tools"

Using "Manage OAuth domain key" enable key, generate secret, uncheck "Allow access to all APIs".

Using "Manage third party OAuth Client access" enable the APIs you want access to using your domain as "Client Name" and the APIs you want to access e.g. "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" for the calendar.

Then finally create a project in the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), use the APIKey as the serviceKey in the above example and turn on the APIs you need to access.

I am answering this as I kept hitting this question when I was trying to find out why my code was constantly returning 401s. Hope this helps someone as the Google instructions are awful and scattered all over the place at the moment.

Comment: In this example, is "consumerSecret" the same as the "Client secret" as displayed on the Google Apis Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console)?

Also, is the "serviceKey" the same as the Simple API Access API Key from the console?

Comment: @Rob Gibbens No, they can only be used for 3-legged.

Comment: The link to the blog post is dead... and it seams to me 2LO is not possible with OAuth 2.0, and this is what the client library uses... can you confirm this method still works ?

Comment: @billy, updated the blog post location, looks like the same article as far as I can remember with a little less explanation. It all still works as far as I know, I have a few apps using this method.

Comment: What OAuth dll do you use ? Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.dll ?

Comment: @billy Google probably supports OAuth 1.0 until April 2015. OAuth 2.0 also has a 2-legged flow, called *Client Credentials Grant*, which is implemented by Google using *Service Accounts*.

Comment: Ok, so I'd be better off using OAuth 2.0 2LO... could you give me a hint on how to use that with the .NET client lib ?

Comment: @billy Google don't seem to have finished the .Net apis to do this at the moment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount It unfortunately only has Java, PHP & Python support

Comment: ...ok, but I can't find the OAuth 1.0 dll anywhere : any clue ?

Comment: i am using a trial account and not getting this option, just says 'Manage OAuth Client access'. is it because of the trial or is there some configuration required