# Google calendar API OAUTH

Tags: java, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to make a Java app (stand alone not web based) that connects to Google calendar but im having issues getting past the OAuth stage. I have looked over every part of the Google API i can see.

The newest version i can find is at `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate`

I have downloaded the 2 sets of JAR files they say to (google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev3-1.5.0-beta and gdata-samples.java-1.46.0) and imported the required libraries and dependencies. This gives me deprication errors for about half the classes and some methods (mainly `new Calendar(httpTransport, accessProtectedResource, jsonFactory);`) dont work at all.

Has anyone got a basic example of getting an OAuth token and accessing the Google Calendar API? Am i looking at this the wrong way or am i using an out of date copy of the api?

Is gdata still in use or has it been replaced?
Thanks
Adrian

Comment: GData is still in use but is considered deprecated. Somewhere I read that it will be considered obsolete sometime in 2014. Take a look at this post and see if it answers your question. It's written for C# so maybe it will be too different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899000/c-sharp-google-calendar-v3-2-legged-authentication-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get oauth working then use oauth to call some google api for example calendar.

Start from [google oauth 1 for installed app](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuthForInstalledApps) or [google oauth 2 for installed app](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) or search for "google oauth installed app". [Scrib](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) is a good oauth lib for Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i ended up using the raw http calls and just handling the results and it appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the code is listed wrong in the documentation.  The line below worked for me.

```
Calendar(httpTransport, jsonFactory, accessProtectedResource);
```